# Sql Server Erro 8623: The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan

Tags: sql, sql-server

Banco Sql Server 2012 e 2008.

Me passaram em log o seguinte erro (sql server 2012):

```
error_reported  2017-12-27 09:14:16.2053050 8623    16  1   False   The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer Support Services for more information.    

SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(e.id_evento) AS count
FROM syo_evento AS e
INNER JOIN syo_encaminhamento AS en ON en.id_evento = e.id_evento 
WHERE en.id_empresa IN (10)
  AND e.id_evento IN (SELECT i.id_evento 
                      FROM syo_interesse AS i
                        INNER JOIN syo_modeloversao ON id_modeloversao = CAST(i.ds_modelo AS INT)
                      WHERE i.ds_modelo != 'INDIFERENTE'
                        AND i.id_interesse = (SELECT MAX(id_interesse) FROM syo_interesse WHERE id_evento = i.id_evento)
                        AND id_modelo = 'STRADA')
                        AND (e.dt_limite <= 1514426360999 OR e.dt_proximaacao <= 1514426360999)
                        AND en.id_statusagenteativo = 'S'
                        AND e.id_evento IN (SELECT i.id_evento FROM syo_interesse AS i WHERE i.ds_marca = 'FIAT' AND i.id_interesse = (SELECT MAX(id_interesse) FROM syo_interesse WHERE id_evento = i.id_evento))
                        AND e.id_evento IN (5964767, 6377920, 6343493, 6343495, 6377927, 6060736, 6343496, 6377935, 6343498, 6343499, 6343509, 6377938, 6184147, 6343510, 6377940, 6377941, 6343504, 6377942, 6343507, 6343506, 6343517, 6377944, 6343512, 6343515, 6377951, 6343514, 6377953, 5999229, 6343523, 6377957, 6343532, 6377960, 6377967, 6343530, 6343531, 
<frame level='1' handle='0x02000000B4EC8B31D255052CB504E32C1088771073F1F154' line='1' offsetStart='0' offsetEnd='0'/> <frame level='2' handle='0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' line='1' offsetStart='0' offsetEnd='0'/>
```

A query acima está incompleta pois o log tem um limite de caracteres, eu reduzi mais ainda devido ao limite do próprio StackOverflow mas apenas na parte de parâmetros do IN, a query no log (incompleta) tem cerca de 3550 parâmetros, mas no sistema já vi buscas com muito mais (centenas de milhares), outro detalhe é que ocorre 37 vezes, num período entre as 09:14 e 11:32 da manhã.

Minha dúvida é, este problema é causado única e exclusivamente pela quantidade de parâmetros na cláusula IN ou pode ter sido agravado por outras queries ?

Por exemplo, uma query pesada, com vários caracteres e que leva alguns segundos para executar, os recursos consumidos por esta query grande irão afetar os recursos desta outra query acima que foi executada depois ou no mesmo momento ?

Ou seja, no caso deste erro os recursos são divididos ou individuais entre as queries ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com o paper [IN (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql), da própria MS, esse problema pode ocorrer quando uma cláusula `IN` possui *um número muito grande de valores (muitos milhares de valores separados por vírgulas) dentro dos parênteses*.

```
-- Caso em que o erro pode ocorrer:
SELECT *
  FROM Tabela
 WHERE id IN (1,2,3,...)  -- milhares de itens
```

Como solução de contorno, o paper sugere que se *armazene os itens da lista em uma tabela e use uma subconsulta SELECT dentro de uma cláusula IN*.

```
-- Como solução de contorno:
-- 1) Criar tabela temporária com os itens 
CREATE TABLE #Temp (id_solicitado int)
INSERT #Temp VALUES (1),(2),(3),... -- milhares de itens

-- 2) Usar uma subquery na cláusula IN.
SELECT *
  FROM Tabela
 WHERE id IN (SELECT id_solicitado FROM #Temp)
```

Sobre suas outras duas perguntas relacionadas ao uso dos recursos durante a execução da query, eu sugiro a leitura do artigo [Guia da Arquitetura de Processamento de Consultas](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide).

Existem vários fatores que vão influenciar esse aspecto. Por exemplo, se o servidor que roda o SQL Server tiver várias CPUs, isso permitirá que várias consultas sejam processadas de forma simultânea. O artigo aborda bem essas questões.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiramente a quantidade que você mencionou na cláusula `IN` não necessariamente é a principal causa do problema, mas obviamente quanto maior a quantidade, mais lenta a consulta. Caso a quantidade fosse `>` 10k poderia ser um bom indicador para seu problema, tive experiências passadas com esse tipo de select.

Veja : [Maximum size for a SQL Server Query? IN clause? Is there a Better Approach [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869753/maximum-size-for-a-sql-server-query-in-clause-is-there-a-better-approach)

Sim, é bem possível que sua query tenha tido um agravamento por outras queries "pesadas" rodando ao mesmo tempo, consumindo muito da máquina onde seu banco está alocado. Já tentou rodar esta query em um horário que não conflite com outras queries? Uma sugestão, você pode usar o SQL Server profiler para monitorar as transações do seu banco em tempo real

E por último, sim, caso mais de uma transação tente acessar o mesmo recurso ao mesmo tempo, dependendo da configuração do seu banco de dados (Read Level), isto pode gerar um deadlock. Para isto separei dois bons artigos sobre o assunto :

[Detectando e encerrando deadlocks](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms178104(v=sql.105).aspx)

[SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql)

Algumas sugestões sobre sua query, não seria possível substituir INDIFERENTE no trecho: `WHERE i.ds_modelo != 'INDIFERENTE'` por algum índice que seja int, em vez de string? A mesma coisa serve para o trecho : `AND id_modelo = 'STRADA')`

Comment: ___"Caso a quantidade fosse > 10k"___, na verdade tenho quase certeza que o IN tem mais de 10 K, conforme falei na descrição da pergunta ___"a query no log (incompleta) tem cerca de 3550 parâmetros"___, a query do log está incompleta.
Realizei testes e o problema no banco do cliente, está ocorrendo para esta query em cerca de 22 mil registros, um pouco mais com algumas alterações da subquery.

Mas o problema foi solucionado já tem um tempo, desculpe a demora para dar retorno, obrigado.

Comment: @TiagoOliveiradeFreitas Interessante, pode dar mais detalhes de como o problema foi solucionado? Obrigado pelo retorno.

Comment: Com um SELECT dentro do IN, conforme o @Fernando indicou, os ids eram gerados de uma busca, só passamos a busca para dentro do IN,
antes era IN ( 1234, 1235, 1236 ... ) agora é IN ( SELECT id_evento FROM ... ).